# Looking for a pattern so my XSD can force the format

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I'm new at this but I'm looking set a pattern in my XSD to have a string formatted as 999.999 where for the left side digits must be between 1 & 999 and the right side digits between 0-999.

Any help would be apprieciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Between" in this context can be understood in two different ways depending if you need exactly three digits or not.

If you need exactly three on each side:

```
[1-9][0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}
```

If you just need a number to be between 1/0 and 999 respectively:

```
[1-9][0-9]{0,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}
```

Explanation:

- `[0-9]` matches any digit, `[1-9]` matches any digit except for zero.
- `x{n}` matches `x` n times, `x{n,m}` matches `x` between n and m times.
- `\.` matches a literal dot.

Comment: Thanks ndn, that is helpful.  Unfortunately I still have to code the number of digits which I was trying to avoid (ie.  x{n} I still have to hard code the n value).  Anyone know a way around that?

Comment: @gmbms, you can place upper bounds as shown in the second example. If there are no bounds, you can use `+` or `*` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The regex for the number you have will be

```
[1-9][0-9]{0,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jO0dS1/2)

In XSD, you do not need any anchors, since the `pattern` attribute value is anchored by default.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to using regex facets against a `xsd:string` base would to use numeric facets such as `xsd:totalDigits`, `xsd:fractionDigits`, and `xsd:minExclusive` against an `xsd:decimal` base:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" > 
  <xsd:element name="x">
    <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal"> 
        <xsd:totalDigits value="6"/> 
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="3"/> 
        <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Depending upon your requirements, this may afford better control over what's acceptable, especially if your data is fundamentally numeric.

Comment: Thanks for your input kjhughes, I'm trying to get away from specifying how many digits are allowed.  This is a string field, so there's no theoretical limit on how many digits can be on the left of right of the decimal.  Looks like I'm going to have to set a limit for now and then continually maintain that number as the system grows....   :-s

Comment: Your comment now differs substantially from your question last year.  In fact, they're contradictory.